# Can I use Lubuntu as a live USB?

Tags: usb, lubuntu, live-usb, virtualization, kali

I was thinking about throwing away my spare laptop hard drive and replace it with a [USB.](https://www.amazon.ca/Apricorn-Validated-256-bit-Encryption-ASK3-8GB/dp/B01AJNIEVY/ref=pd_sbs_147_4?_encoding=UTF8&refRID=1CRWCK77GSKKNVEKTQTN&th=1) Is a 8GB 3.0 USB good enough to run lubuntu and kali linux within lubuntu (in VB)? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's probably not enough space to install 2 OSes onto.